# What can I plant between rows of sunchokes?

Tags: plant-recommendations, shade

I have planted rows of sunchokes in my 10'X15' community garden, so I was wondering what I should plant between the rows of sunchokes. I'm looking for something that I can leave in the ground all season.

They're spaced about 2 feet apart for plenty of growing/spreading room my first year.

Comment: It's invasive and hard to get rid of. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: How close together did you plant the sunchokes? And are sunchokes allowed in the community garden? Ours would not allow that...

Comment: Yes, that was the goal, since that's what city gardens are intended for when you have a 4 acre plot at home.

Comment: I told the arborist in a phone call yesterday that sunchokes are going in the community garden if I can get a plot of land, and he didn't tell the person who runs that program that it wasn't OK to plant them in the community garden, since it's right next to a wide open field. , It's a wildflower in my home state of MN: https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/flower/jerusalem-artichoke

Comment: Yes, they are native here, but some natives do have invasive properties that aren't always welcome in a garden, especially a community garden where the plots are close together and tend to change hands frequently. If they said it was ok, I suppose you are ok, but I wouldn't be surprised if they affair new rule at some point in the near future.

Comment: They are OK with people planting horseradish, and till it every year, so why wouldn't they be OK with planting sunchokes? People will just need to  keep on top of their undesired plants more next year if they don't want it.

Comment: This is my city gardening rules: http://www.ci.lino-lakes.mn.us/vertical/sites/%7BA233BB09-8316-4E17-A27A-C25E01027DA7%7D/uploads/2014__Garden_Plots.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with planting something that will grow all season is that it is going to need to compete with the sunchokes, which will be tall and aggressive. I think you might be able to get a round of radishes and baby lettuce out of the plot before the sunchokes get too tall, but they of course won't last the whole season. Native prairie plants could coexist, but I think you are looking for edibles. Your options are limited.

Comment: So the native prairie plants will eat up all the nitrogen? What do you think of the American Groundnut?